# Any_instance undefined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing

I am writing up a rspec test - and for some reason, i am told that the method any_instance is undefined. I am quite surprised, because I have a very similar expectations in one of my controllers rspec files - and it works fine. Any ideas why this could be happening?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Subscriber do

  it {should belong_to :user}

  describe "send_message should use mobile to send message" do
    subscriber = Subscriber.new(:number => "123")
    Mobile.any_instance.should_receive(:send_sms).with("123")
    subscriber.send_message("hello!")
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
/subscriber_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': 
undefined method `any_instance' for Mobile:Class (NoMethodError)
```

My rspec version (taken from my gemfile is)

> gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.11.0", :group => [:development, :test]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really clear: you didn't wrap your test in an `it` block. That's all.

Comment: oh damn. embarressed to have asked this now. Thanks!

Comment: you know what? it made me crazy once, I've just learnt the lesson ;)

Comment: @Newton: This happens to every RSpec user at some point. It's like an initiation. So celebrate -- today you are a man!

Comment: If you use `before` blocks in RSpec and have some confusion: This works in `before :each` blocks but NOT in `before :all` blocks.